# PackagesNotFoundError while installing torch using anaconda on Mac OS Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: macos, anaconda, torch

I use "(pytorch) eben:~ eben_hu$ conda install torch" to install torch in my environment "pytorch", and here is the result:
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- torch

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I wonder why there's no such package in the anaconda?

Answer (score 5):

Conda's name for the pytorch package is `pytorch` (unlike pip's which is `torch`)
Therefore this should be the right command for mac:
`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch`